# mysql Script for updating data in a second foreign key column using an existing foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

1. I have 3 tables. Leagues, teams, players. Each team belongs to only one league and each player belongs to only one team. Every player is on a team and every team is in a league.
2. Table 2 [teams] has a foreign key to table 1 [leagues]. ( t2fk = t1id)
3. Table 3 [players] has a foreign key to table 2 [teams]. (t3fk = t2id)
4. I want to use the above relationship to write a script that adds [t1id] to table 3 as a second foreign
   key. In other words, I want to add the league id [t1id] to the players table using
   the shared relationship with teams.
5. The end goal is for table 3 to have two foreign keys [t3fk = t2id] and [t3fk = t1id].

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions - an attempt at least is expected..

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I don't see how it's applicable. Do you have any suggestions on how I can figure out how to solve this problem?